# What could cause Magento to change new address back to default address on Paypal redirect?

Tags: magento, paypal

I'm getting a strange bug in Onepage checkout using Paypal Express.

Logged-in Customer enters new billing address "on-the-fly", sets 'Save in Addressbook' and 'Ship to this address', then proceeds through checkout.

**Address is saved in the database correctly at this point.**

Customer chooses Paypal and Magento goes through it's logic (collection totals, saving quote - twice and data checks, etc).

I've stepped through the logic using Xdebug and am not able to pinpoint exactly where but right before redirecting to Paypal in /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php on line 318 in afterSave() callback, there's a line

```
if (null !== $this->_addresses) {
    $this->getAddressesCollection()->save();
}
```

In $this->getAddressesCollection(), the billing and shipping addresses are wrong, they're both the Customer's default.  However, the database is still correct.

Once the ->save() fires, the correct ones are overwritten.

It certainly appears to be Magento bug but I need to find a solution.  This is EE 1.11.1.0.

Anyone experienced this before?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find what causes this? I've just run into the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar bug and maybe its the same with you. If you select an address as your default address in the address book it screws up the one page checkout.

Say I have 3 people in my address book: John, Suzy and Bill.

One day I happen to be in my address book and I select John as my default billing and shipping address. Then I go to my cart, order some items, select John as billing, and select ship to a different address. On the next step I select Suzy as my ship to address. I click next to go to the shipping method step, but whoa, wait! Suzy's address has been overwritten and replaced with Johns address.

Its exactly the same issue posted about here (although I dont think the guy understands what happened, but the screenshots are the same result): http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/7520/P0/

The issue is in the opcheckout.js file. I have a fix. basically once a default address is selected the add new address form (hidden form) is always populated with your default address.

Normally, without a default address selected in address book, I believe that the opcheckout.js properly fills in the hidden fields with the address you selected in the select box.

The following modified opcheckout.js script: ( http://pastebin.com/chiwyRJZ ) will fix it so that the hidden fields are properly filled with the correct data. From what I understand is this is an old unfixed bug, perhaps from whichever version Magento added the Add New Address form in one page checkout

To apply the fix, copy the code from paste bin and replace it with the code in your themes opcheckout.js

Usually opcheckout.js is in skin\frontend\default\yourtheme\js

OR

\skin\frontend\base\default\js

Answer (score -2):

I know it is too late to post this, but I faced this issue on Magento 1.9.x. not only on paypal, but all other payment methods.

Check this method witch called upon creating new Quote:

```
public function assignCustomerWithAddressChange
```